# How do I change the color of the shaded region for the plot_implicit function from the sympy_plot_backends module?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

I cannot set the color of the shaded region while using plot_Implicit from the spb module. It should be as simple as passing a 'colors' parameter as that's what the backend contourf function takes, but it doesn't work.

I have tried                                                    `plot = plot_implicit(formattedQ, (x,-5,5),(y,-5,5),show=False,adaptive =False, rendering_kw={'colors': 'red'})`` as well as `plot = plot_implicit(formattedQ, (x,-5,5),(y,-5,5),show=False,adaptive =False, rendering_kw={'colors': ['red']})` and `plot = plot_implicit(formattedQ, (x,-5,5),(y,-5,5), show=False, adaptive=False, line_color='red')`, as well as a bunch of similar variations. All I am trying to do is change the color of the lines plotted, NOT by using cmap. I either end up getting an error like this

> stderr: raise ValueError('Either colors or cmap must be None')`

or no error but the graph remains unchanged.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
from spb import plot_implicit
from sympy import symbols

x, y = symbols("x y")
plot = plot_implicit(
    eval("y<x"),
    (x, -5, 5),
    (y, -5, 5),
    show=True,
    adaptive=False,
    rendering_kw={"colors": ["red"]},
)
```

Comment: I'm the developer of the module. Sadly, you didn't provide the expression to be plotted... As such nobody can replicate your issue. :|

Comment: @JoshuaGuevara, please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PawelKam Just added it, sorry for the formatting I tried spacing it out and it looked fine in the preview but the spacing is still wonky

Comment: @Davide_sd I just added a reproducible example with the simple expression 'y<x', apologies as I didn't think that the expression itself was relevant as plot_implicit IS plotting, just not styling no matter what I try.

Comment: In the future you can refer to [this site for help with markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot_implicit` uses two strategies to visualize expressions:

- if `adaptive=True`, it uses matplotlib's `fill` command. As of version 1.6.7, it is not possible to set custom rendering keywords for this kind of plots.
- if `adaptive=False`, it uses matplotlib's `contour` or `contourf`, which requires colormaps. This is how you can set your custom colormaps:

```py
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# NOTE: #ffffff00 is transparent color
cmap = ListedColormap(["#ffffff00", "red"])

x, y = symbols("x y")
plot = plot_implicit(
    eval("y<x"),
    (x, -5, 5),
    (y, -5, 5),
    show=True,
    adaptive=False,
    rendering_kw={"cmap": cmap},
)
```